# Masking two square matrices

Tags: python

I'm new to python and there is something that I am not sure how to do it. I have the following Matrices:

```
A=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
B=[[False,True,False],[True,False,True],[False,True,False]]
```

I would like to use B to transform A into the following Matrix:

```
A=[[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]]
```

I'm sure it is quite simple but, as said, I'm new to python so if you could tell me how to do that I'd appreciate it.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet for this is to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 2, 3,],
                 [4, 5, 6,],
                 [7, 8, 9,],])
mask = np.array([[False, True,  False,],
                 [True,  False, True,],
                 [False, True,  False,],])

filtered_data = data * mask
```

which results in `filtered_data` of:

```
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [0, 8, 0]])
```

Without numpy you can do it with a nested list comprehension, but I'm sure you'll agree the numpy solution is much clearer if it's an option:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3,],
        [4, 5, 6,],
        [7, 8, 9,],]
mask = [[False, True,  False,],
        [True,  False, True,],
        [False, True,  False,],]

filtered_data = [[data_elem if mask_elem else 0 
                  for data_elem, mask_elem in zip(data_row, mask_row)]
                 for data_row, mask_row in zip(data, mask)]
```

which gives you `filtered_data` equal to

```
[[0, 2, 0], [4, 0, 6], [0, 8, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
A=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
B=[[False,True,False],[True,False,True],[False,True,False]]

for ind, val in enumerate(B):
    for sub_ind, sub_val in enumerate(val):
        A[ind][sub_ind] = int(sub_val)

print(A)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

With [numpy.multiply](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) you'll get what you want:

```
import numpy as np

A=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
B=[[False,True,False],[True,False,True],[False,True,False]]

np.multiply(A, B)

#array([[0, 1, 0],
#       [1, 0, 1],
#       [0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: You can use the `*` operator for this. It's far more common and readable.

Comment: @Dan Sure, but this way you don't need to convert `A` and `B` before multiplying :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
[ [int(y) for y in x]  for x in B ]
```

Doing `int()` on a Boolean.

`int(False)` --> `0`
`int(True)`  --> `1`

Answer (score 0):

Basic doble for loop:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        A[i][j]= int(B[i][j])*A[i][j]
print (A)
```

output:

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
```

example:

```
A=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]]
B=[[False,True,False],[True,False,True],[False,True,False]]
```

output:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        A[i][j]= int(B[i][j])*A[i][j]
print (A)
```

Comment: `A[i][j]= int(B[i][j])*A[i][j]` as OP cares about the values of `A`

Comment: @OlvinRoght only when all the values of `A` are `1`

Comment: @Dan, actually, not.

Comment: @OlvinRoght `int(3 == True)` returns `0`...?

Comment: @Dan, it works with `1` and `0`, not only with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
A=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
B=[[False,True,False],[True,False,True],[False,True,False]]
X = [[x and y for x,y in zip(a,b)] for a,b in zip(A,B)]
C = [ [int(x) for x in c]  for c in X ]


print(C)
```

output

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: This doesn't actually use the values of `A`. It only works if they're all `1`

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have asked A to modified. Here's a solution, that doesn't create a new list, but modifies A. It uses `zip` and `enumerate`

```
A=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
B=[[False,True,False],[True,False,True],[False,True,False]]

for x,y in zip(A,B):
    for x1,y1 in zip(enumerate(x),y):
        x[x1[0]] = int(y1)

print A
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify `A` using flags in `B`, you can do it like that:

```
A = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
B = [[False, True, False], [True, False, True], [False, True, False]]

C = [[int(A_el == B_el) for A_el, B_el in zip(A_ar, B_ar)] for A_ar, B_ar in zip(A, B)]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Also you can iterate using indexes:

```
C = [[int(A[i][j] == B[i][j]) for j in range(len(A[0]))] for i in range(len(A))
```